# What is Mixin and when to use it in the polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, multiple-inheritance, polymer-2.x

I am quite new to Polymer framework and was checking if we can inherit from multiple classes in it, then I came across idea of Mixin. Still I have some confusions about it. I need good examples explaining idea of Composition, Multiple inheritance and role of Mixin to achieve it. I shall be grateful for the help.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#mixins

Answer (score 3):

**Mixins**

> A mixin is an abstract subclass; i.e. a subclass definition that may be applied to different superclasses to create a related family of modified classes. - Gilad Bracha and William Cook, Mixin-based Inheritance

In simpler words a class expression mixins let you share code between elements without adding a common superclass. In Polymer a mixin looks similar to a typical Polymer prototype and can define lifecycle callbacks, declared properties, default attributes, observers, and event listeners

Here is a simple example

```
SelectedMixin = function (superClass) {
return class extends superClass {

    static get properties() {
        return {
            isSelected: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false,
                notify: true,
                observer: '_selectedChanged'
            }
        };
    }

    _selectedChanged(selected) { 
        // do something
    }

    getSelectedItems() {
        // do something
    }
   }
}


class MyElement1 extends SelectedMixin(Polymer.Element) { 

      hightligh(){
            const selected = this.getSelectedItems();
            // do something
      }
}

class MyElement2 extends SelectedMixin(Polymer.Element) { 

    sort(){
        const selected = this.getSelectedItems();
        // do something
    }
}
```

You can see that we reused the `SelectedMixin` with two elements without the need to duplicate the code in the two elements.
If you have more than one mixin then you can use them like this

```
class MyElement extends MixinB(MixinA(Polymer.Element)) { ... }
```

You can read more about mixins from [here](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/)

Polymer 2 supports also behaviors which work in a similar way to mixins.

**Behaviors**

Polymer 1 supported extending custom element prototypes with shared code modules called behaviors.

A simple example for behaviors can be written like this

```
<script>
SelectedBehavior = {

  properties: {
    isSelected: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false,
      notify: true,
      observer: '_selectedChanged'
    }
  },

  _selectedChanged: function(selected) {
      // do something 
  },
};
<script>

<script>
  Polymer({
     is: 'my-element',
     behaviors: [SelectedBehavior]
  });
<script>
```

In Polymer 2 these behaviors cannot be used anymore like this. instead, you use them like this

```
<script>

  class MyElement extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors(
     [SelectedBehavior] , Polymer.Element) 
  {
      static get is() { return 'my-element' }
  }
</script>
```